# Delphi HtmlHelpAPI- How to direct a CHM file to open to different sections

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, chm

I am able to open a CHM file by passing a ShortInteger and casting it as a Word for the dwData parameter. I.E.

```
Unit Help;   //this is where the Id's are set with their description
 Interface
 Const

Address_File = 35;  //delphi identifies Address_File as a shortint
etc..
```

Call get help pass my ID

```
GetHelp(Address_File); //call get help pass my ID to open to the Address_File topic
```

GetHelp procedure

```
procedure GetHelp(HelpID : Word);
begin
  Application.HelpFile := ProgramPath + 'help.chm';
  HtmlHelpW(0, PWideChar(Application.HelpFile),HH_HELP_CONTEXT , HelpID);
end;
```

HtmlHelpW function

```
function HtmlHelpW(hwndCaller : HWND; pszFile: PWideChar; uCommand : Integer;
         dwData : DWORD) : HWND; stdcall; external 'hhctrl.ocx' name 'HtmlHelpW';
```

As I pass different ShortIntegers I am able to initialize the help file at different sections.
However I can't figure out how the values are mapped.  There are some sections in the chm file that I want to be able to map to but the short Integer or context ID associated with them is not documented in the program or is not mapped.

Comment: You will have to do the dirty work of making sure every topic in the help file has a **unique** ID, then use that ID appropriately in the application. I personally use constants for every possible topic, then dynamically call those constants in the app as necessary from different places.

Comment: Okay how do I find and set the "unique ID's" in the help file?  I did try Decompiling my CHM file to see if I could find these unique Id's but was unsuccessful.

Comment: I cannot understand the question. Could you try and explain a bit more.

Comment: I've also been unsuccessful in getting those ID's when uncompiling. I believe you need to know them upon compilation. I'm still in the process (after a year) of re-writing our help file for this exact reason (among others).

Comment: Adding, decompiling doesn't give you the entire thing. Context ID's (which is what we're talking about) is one thing that it can't decompile, then there's also search keywords, hierarchy (tree of topics), etc. Pretty much, all that's salvaged when decompiling is the HTML pages and the Images.

Comment: If you wrote the help file, you should have assigned the context IDs that are passed in the `dwData` parameter. If you didn't write it, there's no way to obtain them, and you'll need to open to the contents or search sections. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869296%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has info on how to create HTML help files and the content needed to accomplish different tasks.

Comment: Why are you casting a dwData to a Word? It's a DWord?

Comment: From the edit to your question: What I'm understanding is you would like to know the mapping between the Help File's Context ID's on each topic and the controls in your application to know how to open certain topics. The method in which you are opening the help file is irrelevant in this case. Only the very last paragraph in your question is relevant.

Comment: Yeah I was just trying to demonstrate to Sertac what I ment by sending a word as the parameter for dwData

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Free Pascal comes with a chmls.exe util that has a command that tries to recover the alias (context) data:

```
chmls, a CHM utility. (c) 2010 Free Pascal core.

Usage: chmls [switches] [command] [command specific parameters]

Switches :
 -h, --help     : this screen
 -p, --no-page  : do not page list output
 -n,--name-only : only show "name" column in list output

Where command is one of the following or if omitted, equal to LIST.
 list       <filename> [section number]
            Shows contents of the archive's directory
 extract    <chm filename> <filename to extract> [saveasname]
            Extracts file "filename to get" from archive "filename",
            and, if specified, saves it to [saveasname]
 extractall <chm filename> [directory]
            Extracts all files from archive "filename" to directory
            "directory"
 unblockchm <filespec1> [filespec2] ..
            Mass unblocks (XPsp2+) the relevant CHMs. Multiple files
            and wildcards allowed
 extractalias <chmfilename> [basefilename] [symbolprefix]
            Extracts context info from file "chmfilename"
            to a "basefilename".h and "basefilename".ali,
            using symbols "symbolprefix"contextnr
 extracttoc <chmfilename> [filename]
            Extracts the toc (mainly to check binary TOC)
 extractindex <chmfilename> [filename]
            Extracts the index (mainly to check binary index)
```

This might be a start, since at least you'll know which pages are exported using an ID, and maybe the URL names will give some information.

The util is in recent releases (make sure you get 2.6.0) and also available in Free Pascal source, which should be convertable to Delphi with relatively minor effort.

Basically the chmls tool was created out of various test codebases. The testprograms decompiled and printed contents of different CHM sections and were used while creating the helpfile compiler, chmcmd, which is also part of FPC.

Comment: If you think so, don't forget to check the chmcmd.exe util :-)

Answer (score 2):

In Delphi, calling a help file is rather easy. In any VCL Forms application, you can set the `HelpContext` property of almost any control to a unique Context ID, which corresponds to a particular topic in the Help File. The Help File was compiled with these mappings, but when you decompile it, these mappings are no longer there. You must have access to the original help file project in order to know these ID's.

1. Set `HelpContext` of controls to the corresponding Context ID in the Help File
2. Set `HelpType` of controls to `htContext` to use the `HelpContext` ID
3. Assign `Application.HelpFile` to the appropriate location of the CHM file
4. When pressing `F1` anywhere in your application, the help file will open based on the Help Context ID on the control, or its parent control

If you don't have the original project, and you don't want to re-create it, then you would have a long task of iterating through the Context ID's of your help file. Try to call the help file starting from 0 through 1,000 or possibly 50,000, depending on the size of it.

A practice I implement is a set of constants in a designated unit called `HelpConstants.pas` which is shared across our common application base. Each constant name uniquely and briefly describes the topic which it represents. Upon starting the application, I dynamically assign these Context ID's to their corresponding controls (usually forms) and VCL takes care of the rest.

Comment: So to clarify: Your suggested answer is to write an app that generates a sequence of hundreds (or possibly thousands) of calls to `HTMLHelp` with sequential values and take notes about which ones open for each value passed, in order to connect them to your app's controls. Have I got that right? (The paragraph right after the numbered list is the only part that addresses the question asked.) If so, you should probably expect a bunch of downvotes (including mine) - that's not a useful solution.

Comment: That's essentially the only way to recover these ID's if you don't have access to the original help file source.

Comment: It's not a practical solution, though. "I'll sit here, start my app at HelpContext 1, and start calling HTMLHelp with incrementing values. If I get a hit, I'll write down what topic it seems to work for along with the value. I'll do this 1000 or 10000 or 50000 times, and hopefully in a year or two I'll have documenation links I can use. Wait! Better yet - I'll just assign new help context IDs to the topic of my help file from scratch and use them instead! Yeah, that's the ticket! Let's do that instead!

Comment: Can you think of an easier way to recover an existing help file without decompiling/rewriting/restructuring?

Comment: Well knowing that its impossible to identify the mappings without the original project is useful information.  I kept trying to find the Id's without success.  Luckily in my situation most of the help file  is already documented, however they missed a couple of sections but similar topics share numbers close to each other. So I may be able to find it without too much trouble. I hadn't attempted this before because I figured there was another way.  If I can't find it I guess I'll have to track down the source or create a new one.  Thanks for your input everyone.

Comment: I'll leave this question unanswered for a little while in case someone happens to know a way to recover these ID's..  But thanks for the information Jerry, at least now I won't keep relentlessly searching for a way to Identify these ID's, believing its something simple i'm missing.

Comment: Trevor: FreePascal chmls util, "chmls extractalias <chm file>". Whole shebang is available in FPC source will try to extract the id to url mapping. Not a whole solution, but maybe symbolnames and the list of topics exposed by id will help

Comment: Clearly the help file contains the information. If it didn't, then the help file would be useless.

Comment: Note: The help authoring software I use (WinCHM) doesn't necessarily require you to specify a context ID, it's optional and can be left blank. However, upon creation of any new topic, it defaults this ID to the next increment after 1,000.

Answer (score 1):

I got the utility Marco suggested from 
https://github.com/alrieckert/freepascal_arm/blob/master/packages/chm/bin/i386-win32/chmls.exe
(download by selecting View Raw).
I was able to extract all the context tags from the .chm help file and add the one I was interested in to my C++ Builder program by calling Application->HelpJump().
HTH